# Reporting API v4 Google analytics engagemntRate

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I succeed to get data with this collector: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

From what I know, bounceRate was used only on UA ​​and it is replaced by EngagementRate on GA4. Yet ga:bounceRate works as a metric while ga:engagementRate does not. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google analytics reporting api which you are currently using is designed to work only with Universals analytics.

As noted in the [overview page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4)

[image]

ga:bounceRate works because its is universal analytics ga:engagementRate does not because it is not a Universal analytics metric.

If you are trying to extract data from a GA4 google analytics account then switch to the [Google analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1)